# How to host Rasa core bot on IIS?

Tags: iis, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I have developed a Rasa bot by using core rasa framework. Rasa server only runs on HTTP protocol. I have only choice of using IIS as a webserver to make this application secured. Can anybody give a step by step process for Rasa bot to be configured using IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution which comes to mind is to simply forward your requests to the Rasa Open Source server and using IIS as proxy.

Comment: Can you pls specify detailed steps I am trying to configure it, but not successful

Comment: Hi You got  solution. i am trying same  please give details so i can use    @Tobias  thank you in advance

Comment: @smith99 hi please give details for this solution